# How to estimate the probability that a number, $x>P^2$, is prime when $x$ is not divisible by all the primes up to prime $P$.

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How to estimate the probability that a number, $x>P^2$, is prime when $x$ is not divisible by all the primes up to prime $P$.

I apologise that this question is so inelegant and vague.

**Background.**

Within some code for this question [The equation $x^n+y^n+z^n=u^n+v^n+w^n=p$, where $p$ is prime.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221371/the-equation-xnynzn-unvnwn-p-where-p-is-prime/2226028#2226028) I used a list of all primes (up to $P$) for trial division of candidates both below and above $P^2$. Then I manually checked those not rejected and $>P^2$ using online prime tests, and noticed that many were, in fact, prime.

**My efforts so far.**

I decided that looking at a range of $x$ values could be of more value than investigating each single $x$, and started looking at the ranges $(kP^2+1,(k+1)kP^2)$ for $k=1,2,3,4,5…$

For small values all cases are countable, so that’s what I did. With $P=5$ I found the probability bounced around making understanding the figures difficult.

I use Z(P, k) for the probability that a number, not divisible by any prime up to $P$, is prime, in the ranges starting from $((k-1)P^2+1,kP^2)$, with $k=2,3,4,...$

For example, I found these probabilities, shown as percentages to 2 decimals. (The second value is for $k=4697$ and so on.)

$$Z(5,4696)= (16.67,14.29,57.14,0,28.57,50,50,28.57,14.29,28.57,14.29,50,16.67,57.14)$$

**My next stage.**

I looked at using the ranges $(P^2+1,kP^2)$. Now

$$Z(5,4696)=
(35.37,35.36,35.37,35.36,35.36,35.36,35.36,35.36,35.36,35.36,35.35,35.36,35.35,35.36)$$

As I continued, $Z(5,20000)=31.15$, but I don’t know exactly where it is heading.

I’ve produced many more results, but I’ll just note a few.

$$Z(541,14)=(80.41)$$
$$Z(1583,21)=(80.10)$$
$$Z(9973,2)=(96.22,93.86,92.17,90.87)$$

**My attempt at theory.**

Clearly, repeated division and counting soon becomes impractical.
I can find the number of primes between two numbers from a prime list, or estimate from a formula.
However, finding the number of composites, prime to all primes up to $P$, is giving me problems.

Working with the example $P=5$, I can see the list starts with $24$ such composites with two factors, $49$ to $323$. However, $343$ is a cube, and I just can’t see how to progress further.

**My questions.**

How to estimate the probability that a number, $x>P^2$, is prime when $x$ is not divisible by all the primes up to prime $P$.

Is it best, in terms of insight, to consider the ranges $(P^2+1,kP^2)$?

Would it be easier to work with $\pi(n)$?

Although it would be nice to know limits as $x$ zooms off to infinity, I’m more interested when $x<8E+24$.
I’m especially keen for numerical values when $P= 982451653$, which I think is $\pi(50000000)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $x$ is random number, we need to estimate$$\prod_{P<p\le\sqrt{x}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$$and we can utilize [Mertens' 3rd theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems). By the theorem,$$\prod_{p\le M}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\approx \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln M}$$and$$\prod_{P<p\le\sqrt{x}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\approx\frac{e^{-\gamma}/\ln \sqrt{x}}{e^{-\gamma}/\ln P}=\frac{2\ln P}{\ln x}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the trouble to answer my question. I will need some time to study your answer, as I don’t yet understand it. May I ask if $P$ and $x$ are the same as in my question, and the final result is the probability I requested?
Do I need to know what $M$ represents?

Comment: @OldPeter, $P$ and $x$ are same as in your question and $2 \ln P/\ln x$ is the probability. $M$ can be any positive number according to the theorem.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond; life interrupting maths.

Thanks for your most elegant solution. Estimates from this solution fit my test data far better than I expected.